# android_core pubsub tutorial

Tags: android-core, rosjava, android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!
I would like to modify the pubsub tutorial in order to have the subscriber running on the AVD and the publisher on my PC.
The pubsub tutorial without modifications works, but if I use the command "*rostopic pub /chatter std_msgs/String "..."*" I don't see the string on the avd screen and if I call "*rostopic echo /chatter*" I can't see what is published by talker. 
Using "*rostopic list*" I get:

```
/chatter<br>
/rosout<br>
/rosout_agg
```

Using "*rostopic info /chatter*":

```
Type: std_msgs/String

Publishers: 
 * /rosjava_tutorial_pubsub/talker (http://127.0.0.1:42623/)
 * /rostopic_5792_1348480888907 (http://camilla-TECRA-A5:35002/)

Subscribers: 
 * /android_gingerbread/ros_text_view (http://127.0.0.1:43231/)
```

Therefore what should I do to put in communication a talker and a subscriber that are running on an avd and on a PC?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/44472/android_core-pubsub-tutorial/) by [camilla](https://answers.ros.org/users/2828/camilla/) on ROS Answers with karma: 255 on 2012-09-24

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [magnux](https://answers.ros.org/users/20495/magnux/) on 2014-10-17**:
Did you managed to solved this issue? I'm having the same problem, but the selected answer isn't helping me. NodeConfiguration is already public, I have the Master URI correctly setted (I think), and I still can't see anything outside the emulator.

**Comment by [magnux](https://answers.ros.org/users/20495/magnux/) on 2014-10-17**:
The problem is to get to the net interface of the virtual device. The same setup on a real device work fine. Solution: use a real device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to make sure your network is set up correctly. E.g. if the roscore is running on the Android device, you need to set the ROS_MASTER_URI on the PC to point to it. Have a look at the [network setup page](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/NetworkSetup).

**Edit** The node configuration in the andoid tutorial is created with `NodeConfiguration.newPrivate()` which creates a private ros node. Use `NodeConfiguration.newPublic()` instead. You will have to specify the host name of your android device. The following code should work:

```
NodeConfiguration nodeConfiguration = 
    NodeConfiguration.newPublic(InetAddressFactory.newNonLoopback().
                                getHostAddress(), masterUri);
```

Note that you need to substitute `masterUri` with your actual master uri.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-09-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [camilla](https://answers.ros.org/users/2828/camilla/) on 2012-09-24**:
How can i get the IP of the avd?

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-09-24**:
The port of the ros core is per default always 11311.

**Comment by [camilla](https://answers.ros.org/users/2828/camilla/) on 2012-09-24**:
Ok but how should I set the ROS_MASTER_URI?Because I launched roscore on the pc and I added this "master_uri  = new java.net.URI("http://172.16.31.203:11311");nodeConfiguration.setMasterUri(master_uri);" to the original code of tutorial pub sub but it doesn't work

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-09-24**:
This looks fine given `172.16.31.203` is the IP address of your PC, not of your tablet. The ROS_MASTER_URI on your PC needs to be the same: `export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://172.16.31.203:11311`

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-09-24**:
Did you configure a DNS? Did you go through the network setup page? Did you set ROS_IP? According to the output of `rostopic info`, the tablet and your computer advertise themselves as `127.0.0.1` which is clearly wrong. Use their public ip on the  android device and on the pc.

**Comment by [camilla](https://answers.ros.org/users/2828/camilla/) on 2012-09-24**:
I set the ROS_MASTER_URI as you write and also the ROS_IP (export ROS_IP=172.16.31.203). Now when I run rostopic info the PC advertise himself with the public IP in fact I get:/rostopic_2423_1348561733505 (http://172.16.31.203:52624/) but I don't know what to do to use the public IP of the avd

**Comment by [camilla](https://answers.ros.org/users/2828/camilla/) on 2012-09-24**:
I know that the IP address of an android avd is 10.0.2.15. But I don't know what should I set to solve the problem. Moreover I read the network setup page and when i do ping 10.0.2.15 on my PC it can't send the messages.